# testing spark jobs with mocks

Tags: scala, unit-testing, apache-spark, mockito

I have spark job like:

```
stream.
..do some stuff..
map(HbaseEventProcesser.process)
```

for now HbaseEventProcesser is an scala Object (singleton). So, there is no problems with serialization.

The problem is in testing that spark job (holdenkarau spark-test lib is used). I want to mock HbaseEventProcessor with some other implementation. I've tried two approaches

- pass implenetation to spark job (as a constructor argument and than invoke methods inside map). That cause problem with serialization issue
- use powerMock. Unfortunately, deepcopy operation failed if SharedSparkContext is used.

Is there any other workarounds ?

Answer (score 0):

You have at least these options:

1) make HbaseEventProcesser regular class that extends some pure trait EventProcessor, and than mock it with framework of you choice

2) refactor you code to smth like this

```
def mapStream[T, R](stream: DStream[T], process: T => R) = {
 stream.
 ..do some stuff..
 map(process)
}

//in main code:
mapStream(stream, HbaseEventProcesser.process)

//in test code:
mapStream(stream, customFunc)
```

Comment: this is the first i did. However, it causes serialization issue. 

I meen: to have class HBaseEventProcessor extend EventProcessor and SparkJob(eventProcessor: EventProcessor) {.... rdd.map(eventProcessor)}

Comment: did you try to make it serializable: `class HBaseEventProcessor extends java.io.Serializable with EventProcessor `?

Comment: Sure, as result i get:  Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException .....- object (class com......ClientDerivedEventsStreamingJob$$anonfun$preStream$2$$anonfun$9, <function1>)

Comment: ensure, that your instance does not capture outer scope, declaring it as local value(on stack), but not as class property or lambda.